# Changes made to Active Directory Audit Logs starting in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, windows-event-log

I apologize for asking a question on a very old operating system:

A client I work with has Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 Domain controllers.  However they're still operating in a Windows Server 2003 Domain and Forest functional level (yes, this is bad, end of life, and unsupported, and a work in progress to convince them to elevate it).

They're trying to retrieve logs regarding a change to an active directory user account.  I know that there were a variety of enhancements done to Event logging starting with Windows Server 2008 to record more info about what attributes were modified, etc, and *I'm pretty sure the schema needed to be elevated in order for the eventlog to record these other elements and attributes.*

The client I'm working with is looking for documentation to this effect, and I'm having a really hard time finding official documentation from Microsoft regarding the enhancements to the eventlog.

Can anyone confirm that this is the case, or point me in the direction of where these changes are recorded by Microsoft?

Comment: `I'm pretty sure the schema needed to be elevated in order for the eventlog to record these other elements and attributes.`. No it does not.  All you would need to do is enable the auditing to find out.  It takes about five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To Detect User Account Changes in Active Directory, you need to enable audit policies on the Default Domain Controller Security Policy GPO. Enable the "Audit user account management" audit policy.

Then you can look for events like user account creation, user account deleted or user account changed, etc..

Here I found an informative post which lets you in step-wise to record changes made in Active Directory: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/129229-how-to-record-changes-made-in-active-directory

Hope this helps!